# How to set MySQL *system_time_zone* to UTC without changing my system clock?

Tags: mysql

```
show variables like '%zone%';

+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| system_time_zone | MST   |
| time_zone        | UTC   |
+------------------+-------+

select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.31    |
+-----------+
```

My physical location changes periodically, which usually means I'm in a different  timezone. For example, last week I was in PST, and this week I'm in MST.

When I started working again on a JVM based application I'm developing, I got an error along the lines of:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Digging into the matter I ran across [this issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/illegalargumentexception-hour_of_day-1063564762.html); the cause: "The database has a value stored for a DATETIME (in my case a TIME column) value that is within the DST lost hour."

That would be fine if I actually cared about timezones, I don't. Let me UTC all the things and get on with my day. I have `/etc/my.cnf` with `default_time_zone='UTC'` and my JDBC driver passes `connectionTimeZone=UTC`, which I'd expect to do the trick but it doesn't. Currently I have to set my laptop's clock to UTC as a workaround, which is IMO, ridiculous.

So, is there a way to bash MySQL over the head and allow me to set `system_time_zone` to UTC even if my actual timezone is PST, MST, EST, etc? Or perhaps a way to only take into account the `time_zone` setting as well would presumably do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html)

> Note
>
> For some Linux platforms, MySQL installation from RPM or Debian
> packages includes systemd support for managing MySQL server startup
> and shutdown. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is not installed because
> it is unnecessary. For more information, see Section 2.5.9, “Managing
> MySQL Server with systemd”.
>
> One implication of the non-use of mysqld_safe on platforms that use
> systemd for server management is that use of [mysqld_safe] or
> [safe_mysqld] sections in option files is not supported and might lead
> to unexpected behavior.

Such as the `timezone` property in `mysqld_safe` section of `/etc/my.cnf` not having any affect on basically every Linux distro that's made the switch to `systemd`.

AFAICT, short of rolling your own `mysqld_safe` startup script, the only way to have the MySQL process actually run in UTC across the board is to set your system clock to UTC.

I'd love to hear otherwise; if not, that's pretty unfortunate.

p.s. `system_time_zone` is *read only* so can't even set it in MySQL CLI

**EDIT**

There is a way using distro supplied `systemd` driven MySQL. On my workstation (Fedora 36), edit `/etc/sysconfig/mysql` and add the "TZ" property; for UTC you would do `TZ=UTC`.

Et voila, `system_time_zone` is now `UTC` regardless of system clock.